# jQuery write to span on select field selection

Tags: jquery, html, e-commerce, append

I'm making a shop with simplecartjs, and the shop has some products that can be bought in different sizes, but with an increment to price. So I tried this, but it didn't write anything to the span. 
So I need it to write the price, depending on the selection, to the item_price span, and if user chooses another selection, then the price must change. Here's my code:

```
<?php
include 'nav.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".item_size").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "25cm") {
            $('.item_price').append("20.00€");
      }
     if ($(this).val() == "50cm") {
            $('.item_price').append("30.00€");
      }
      if ($(this).val() == "100cm") {
            $('.item_price').append("45.00€");
      }
});
</script>
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <h2 class="item_name">Quartz-kalvot </h2>
<p>    <select class="item_size">
        <option value="25cm"> 25cm x 30cm </option>
        <option value="50cm"> 50cm x 30xm</option>
        <option value="100cm"> 100cm x 30xm </option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"><br>
    <span class="item_price"></span><br>
<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a></p>
</div>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: are there any errors? you should use .text("20.00 EUR"). Can you post on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `data` attribute for the price :

```
<select class="item_size">
    <option data-price="20.00€" value="25cm"> 25cm x 30cm </option>
    <option data-price="30.00€" value="50cm"> 50cm x 30xm</option>
    <option data-price="45.00€" value="100cm"> 100cm x 30xm </option>
</select>
```

Then its simply :

```
$(".item_size").change(function(){
    $('.item_price').html($('option:selected',this).data('price'));
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6uHF/2/)

### Update

To work out the price based on quantity use something like this ... remove the `€` symbol from the data attribute

```
<select class="item_size">
    <option data-price="20.00" value="25cm"> 25cm x 30cm </option>
    <option data-price="30.00" value="50cm"> 50cm x 30xm</option>
    <option data-price="45.00" value="100cm"> 100cm x 30xm </option>
</select>
```

Then

```
$(".item_size, .item_Quantity").change(function() {
    var qty = parseInt($('.item_Quantity').val(), 10);
    var price = parseFloat($('.item_size option:selected').data('price'));
    var totalprice = qty * price;
    $('.item_price').html(totalprice.toFixed(2) + "€");
});​
```

You will notice that now I am listening for then `change` event on both `.item_size` and `.item_Quantity` - to ensure that when the size and quantity is changed the price updates. Using [`parseint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the selected values to a `number` then making the calculation (ie price * quantity) to work out the total price ... the number is then displayed to 2 decimal places ([`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed))

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6uHF/1/)

Comment: Mine is very basic and not outside the box; yours is on the other hand, +1 innit bruv! `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit added an update - as i suspect the OP wants something similar to that !!!

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen have a look at the update ... is that what you want

Comment: @ManseUK ha ha lol gotchya `:P` [ bazinga ] question. `:)` removed my answer

Comment: Hmmm. I see it works in the example, but not in my code. Is it possible that simplecartjs overrides it?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen i have no idea what is in `simplecartjs` ... just a question though - how many elements with the class `item_size` / `item_Quantity` and `item_price` have you got on a single page ? because if its multiple then you will need to change the code slightly

Comment: I don't know what you code does, but the shopping cart calculates the total price of the products.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen so just use my first code then - this will take the price from the currently selected item and place that price in the `item_price` div

Comment: Hmmm... None of the codes at this pages does nothing... And there's only one item per page.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen what errors are you getting ? is your code called after the DOM is ready ? ie `$(document).ready(function() { // your code here });`

Comment: http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/using_events
Here's some text about it... Is it possible that it wont allow custom coding?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen just using the first method should do what you need it to do

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen what are you expecting it to do ? what does it do ? can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with all of your code

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/SaL29/1/) - you didnt wait for the DOM to be ready before the code was executed ... you need to do this $(document).ready(function() { // your code here });

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen You cannot interact with the DOM before it is ready ... read the docs for more http://api.jquery.com/ready/ .. i did put this in a comment 5 hours ago !!!

Comment: But what is the DOM? I'm a beginner with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/E7Put/

Append will do something like this: `45.00€30.00€45.00€` when you choose size more than once.